# Excel loop stops working

Tags: excel, vba, merge

I've built an Excel Macro which takes the first sheets from all XLS files in a selected folder (including XLS files in any sub-folders) and copies the sheets onto a single sheet in a new Workbook. The code seems to work fine for the most part and I intend to use it to merge thousands of Excel sheets into a single file.

However the problem is that the loop just stops working at some point, with no errors raised. Sometimes it's a couple of hundred files, sometimes more. But the process seems to be unreliable and I can't tell why.

This is my code (I call the Merge macro which in turn calls the DoFolder Sub):

```
Sub Merge()
    Dim FileSystem As Object
    Dim HostFolder As String
    HostFolder = "C:\XLSfiles"
    Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    DoFolder FileSystem.GetFolder(HostFolder)
End Sub
Sub DoFolder(Folder)
    Dim unusedRow As Long 'used for writing the file path info before each copied sheet
    Dim path As String, ThisWB As String, lngFilecounter As Long
    Dim wbDest As Workbook, shtDest As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim Filename As String, Wkb As Workbook
    Dim CopyRng As Range, Dest As Range
    Dim RowofCopySheet As Integer
    RowofCopySheet = 2 ' Row to start on in the sheets you are copying from
    ThisWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Set shtDest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Dim SubFolder
        For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
        DoFolder SubFolder
    Next
    Dim File
    ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMinimized
    For Each File In Folder.Files
        ' Operate on each file
        unusedRow = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Offset(1, 0).Row
        If Not Filename = ThisWB Then
            Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(File)
            Set CopyRng = Wkb.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(RowofCopySheet, 1),Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count))
            Set Dest = shtDest.Range("A" & shtDest.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1)
            CopyRng.Copy Dest
            Wkb.Close False
        End If
        Cells(unusedRow, 1) = File
        Application.StatusBar = File
    Next
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

What am I missing?

Comment: From your description I would think you simply reach the limit of what a worksheet can hold; this limit being 1,048,576 rows by 16,384 columns.
What _exactly_ is it you wish to achieve? To me this sounds like a case for a database rather than an Excel sheet?

Comment: I don't think that would be the case. Each XLS file has no more than 50 rows of data, and no more than 30-40 columns. So it should be a couple of 100K rows at most, never more than 500K.

Comment: As for the exact purpose, it is to merge the first sheets from a few thousand excel files into a single excel file. So for example if I had 2000 Excel files, and each file had 50 rows of data, my end result would be a single Excel file with 2000 x 50 = 100K rows of data.

Comment: That is what you describe in your post but it is not the exact purpose. _Why_ are you doing this? I suppose it is in order to evaluate/consolidate data of sorts. Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. Instead of copying ranges, you can simply set their value
2. Do not use `Cells` when working with multiple sheets; always explicitely state the object/sheet whose Cells you like to address

Sample that worked for me:

```
For Each fi In f.Files
    If InStr(1, Right(fi.Name, 5), ".xls") > 0 Then

        Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(fi)
        Set ws = Wkb.Sheets(1)

        rowCount = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        colCount = ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count

        ranString = shtDest.Cells(curRow, 1).Address & ":" & shtDest.Cells(curRow + rowCount, colCount).Address
        Set ran = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 1).Address, ws.Cells(rowCount, colCount).Address)
        Set destRan = shtDest.Range(ranString)
        destRan.Value = ran.Value
        curRow = curRow + rowCount

        Wkb.Close False
    End If
Next fi
```

It may look a bit long-winded building a range string first, but it made debugging easier.